# Two sequence Session.set cause one rerun?

Tags: meteor

In Chrome console,

```
> Tracker.autorun(function() {console.log(Session.get('show'))});

> Session.set('show',2);
2
> Session.set('show',3);
3
> Session.set('show',4);Session.set('show',5);
5
```

Two sequence Session.set cause one rerun? 
How can I make it run twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Tracker.flush()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_flush) to immediately rerun the computation after the first reactive data source update :

```
> Session.set("show",4);Tracker.flush();Session.set("show",5);
```